# Database queries in terms of frameworks

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Consider the creation of a picture site with about 20-30k high resolution photos and parallel users opening many of the pictures/thumbnails. The Server-side logic for the database queries could be written in pure PHP like this:

```
 function delete($where, $table){
        return $this->query("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $where");
    }
function count($query, $countTable=true){
        if($countTable)
            return $this->getField ('SELECT count(*) as count FROM '.$query, 'count');
        else
            return $this->getField ('SELECT count(*) as count FROM ('.$query.')', 'count');
    }
```

Is this way of creating Pure PHP 'database tools' effective versus the framework methods?
Which PHP framework offers the best database management tools in terms of speed and big number of parallel queries? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you asking to compare raw sql vs an ORM?

Comment: I'm interested in this type of comparison and the comparison in terms of write-less more efficient code between the different ORM's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that Doctrine is very efficient when it comes to parallelism and stability on high-traffic applications. Have you already tried? It's very well-documented and written, and it's built on top of PDO, so it isn't hard to learn to work with. Have a look.